# PostgreSQL fails to reinstall after upgrading Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade, postgresql

I ran `do-release-upgrade` to update an Ubuntu 12.04 server to Ubuntu 14.04. It seemed to go smoothly, but when I did `apt-get update` after the upgrade I notice the PostgreSQL packages were still looking at the **precise** repos instead of the **trusty** repos. I followed the [instructions here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) to add the trusty repos and moved the `.list` file containing the precise repos to a temporary directory as a backup. After I did that, `sudo apt-get upgrade` failed and I was not able to get it to run completely again even after restoring the **precise** repos. I did not happen to grab the error messages. Since this is a development server and all the data is non-essential, I decided just to re-install PostgreSQL. This repeatedly failed after several attempts to clear out any custom configuration we may have had on the server that I thought might be interfering. I am able to do `sudo apt-get install postgresql-common` successfully, but if I try `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5` it fails with the following:

```
Setting up postgresql-9.5 (9.5.5-1.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Creating new cluster 9.5/main ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.5/main
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
  locale en_US.UTF-8
  socket /var/run/postgresql
  port   5432
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/9.5/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server                                                                                             
 * Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@9.5-main.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@9.5-main.service' for details.
                                                                                                                               [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib-9.5:
 postgresql-contrib-9.5 depends on postgresql-9.5 (= 9.5.5-1.pgdg14.04+1); however:
  Package postgresql-9.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-contrib-9.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up sysstat (10.2.0-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/sar.sysstat to provide /usr/bin/sar (sar) in auto mode
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.5
 postgresql-contrib-9.5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Jan 17 15:31:31 beta kernel: [    4.029504] systemd-journald[543]: Failed to resolve 'systemd-journal' group: No such process
```

If I try `systemctl status postgresql@9.5-main.service` I get:

```
postgresql@9.5-main.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

The `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log` log file is empty, so I'm not sure where else to check for logs. After failing to install, I go through [the steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu) to do a complete uninstallation. I can't tell if this an issue with PostgreSQL or the upgraded server.

**UPDATE:** The output of `dpkg -l "postgresql*"`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                         Version             Architecture        Description
+++-============================-===================-===================-==============================================================
un  postgresql-7.4               <none>              <none>              (no description available)
un  postgresql-8.0               <none>              <none>              (no description available)
un  postgresql-9.1               <none>              <none>              (no description available)
iF  postgresql-9.5               9.5.5-1.pgdg14.04+1 amd64               object-relational SQL database, version 9.5 server
un  postgresql-client            <none>              <none>              (no description available)
ii  postgresql-client-9.5        9.5.5-1.pgdg14.04+1 amd64               front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.5
ii  postgresql-client-common     178.pgdg14.04+1     all                 manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common            178.pgdg14.04+1     all                 PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
iU  postgresql-contrib-9.5       9.5.5-1.pgdg14.04+1 amd64               additional facilities for PostgreSQL
un  postgresql-doc-9.5           <none>              <none>              (no description available)
```

Comment: please post dpkg -l "postgresql*"  to check what's leftover.

Comment: I use the same package with 14.04 successfully and it doesn't use `systemd` (which is not even installed) to start. I suspect that you have parts of  `systemd` installed, so that the postgresql package tries to use it and fails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem, upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. Don't know but it also using systemd. While checking `/etc/init.d/postgresql` file it uses `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions`.

This file executes /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster to start and stop postgresql server.

```
if [ "$1" = "stop" ] || [ "$1" = "restart" ]; then
    ERRMSG=$(pg_ctlcluster --force "$2" "$name" $1 2>&1)
else
    ERRMSG=$(pg_ctlcluster "$2" "$name" $1 2>&1)
fi
```

`/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster` file accepts `--skip-systemctl-redirect` option to start or stop postgresql without systectl.

So you need to add `--skip-systemctl-redirect` in `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions` in do_ctl_all() function.
So it will look like this.

```
if [ "$1" = "stop" ] || [ "$1" = "restart" ]; then
    ERRMSG=$(pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect --force "$2" "$name" $1 2>&1)
else
    ERRMSG=$(pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect "$2" "$name" $1 2>&1)
fi
```

Or you can add `$skip_systemctl_redirect = 1;` before `$skip_systemctl_redirect` is checked in `/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster`.

Comment: As far as I know, Ubuntu 14.04 is not using `systemd`

Comment: @Zanna Well, I did investigate my server which has systemd installed. The main dependency was "upower" and I managed to removed all unnecessary packages dependant of "upower".
Everything goes fine again.

Answer (score 7):

The same issue on Ubuntu upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04

Fixed by adding the line

```
alias pg_ctlcluster="pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect"
```

in `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions`
after

```
init_functions=/lib/lsb/init-functions
```

in puppet it looks like this

```
  package { 'postgresql-common': ensure => 'installed' }
  file_line { 'Patch 1 /usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions':
    path => '/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions',
    line => 'alias pg_ctlcluster="pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect"',
    after => "init_functions=/lib/lsb/init-functions",
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

re-edit:
Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't use systemd by default for service/init management. For some reason, your install *is* using systemd (do you know why?), but it should be using upstart with a wrapper for legacy sysV startup scripts.

The postgresql-9.5 package does not provide a systemd startup unit file, instead it provides a sysV script which upstart handles fine (just tested here).

Possible options:

1. [Switch back to upstart for init management](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Permanent_switch_back_to_upstart)
2. [Write your own systemd startup script for postgresql-9.5](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Example_Systemd_service)

...and I'm out of ideas ;)

Comment: I don't quite understand those links relate to this issue. The [download instructions for Ubuntu](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) recommend `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main`. Is there some way to infer that it is pulling from that `pool/9.5/p/postgresql-9.5/` directory when trying to install `postgresql-9.5`? I did try installing `postgresql-9.6` after uninstalling everything else and unfortunately it didn't get any further.

Comment: The repository contains a bunch of different files for various different purposes. The actual deb packages themselves sit in the pool/ dir under the http:// url part that you posted (try going there with a web browser). Is there any reason you're not using the postgresql packages provided by ubuntu/canonical themselves?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The Ubuntu 14.04 repositories don't contain the latest PostgreSQL version, I don't remember which one they are on, but we need at least 9.4 for some of the extensions we are using.

Comment: ok, I was completely mistaken, it looks like that repo may be a bit of a mess. There's a main/ subdir and there's 9.5 packages under there. I tried installing them here and it went through fine. Updated my post with new information -

Comment: Thanks for looking into it some more. I couldn't figure out how to repair postgresql so we just cloned a similar VM and will rebuild from that. I will have to run through the 12.04 to 14.04 upgrade again, so I'll try to keep track of the upgrade log and identify things related to systemd or postgresql. This seems like the most probable answer, I'll post any new information if I learn anything from the logs.

Answer (score 1):

After search while, I came to this post because my server have multiple versions of Postgresql 9.4, 9.5, 9.6 and got the same behavior.

```
sudo pg_lsclusters 9.4 main status
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.4 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main 
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
9.5 main    5433 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main 
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
9.6 main    5434 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main 
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

Trying to start postgresql keep showing:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.4 main start
Redirecting start request to systemctl
Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@9.4-main.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@9.4-main.service' for details.
```

After read all answers, I like more the answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/877472/130195 
But if wants to keep `systemd` installed which is not fully supported by Ubuntu 14.04 follow that hack.

But I think we don't needs `systemd` and I've used aptitude to know whats is demands to install `systemd` version 204, on my system was `upower`, I don't need `upower` either. 
Removing anything I don't needed anymore and all three versions of postgresql is working again.

I think just a simple `sudo apt-get purge systemd && sudo apt-get autoremove` resolve better the problem by remove `systemd` package.

WARNING: Please, be carefully before remove any package, pay attention to what will remove with very carefully.