# Unable to install postgresql 10 on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I am executing this command to install postgesql in my ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

I am getting a error during installation:

```
Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@10-main.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service' for details
```

Here is the complete logs:

```
Creating config file /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf with new version
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
  en_us
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up postgresql-10 (10.1-1.pgdg14.04+1) ...
Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 10/main ...
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main --auth-local peer --auth-host md5
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_IN".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/10/main ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l logfile start

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
 * Starting PostgreSQL 10 database server                                                                                                               * Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@10-main.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service' for details.
                                                                                                                                                [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-10 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql:
 postgresql depends on postgresql-10; however:
  Package postgresql-10 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib:
 postgresql-contrib depends on postgresql-contrib-10; however:
  Package postgresql-contrib-10 is not installed.
  Package postgresql-10 which provides postgresql-contrib-10 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package postgresql-contrib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                             Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-10
 postgresql
 postgresql-contrib
```

this is the output of `systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service`

```
ajit@AjitSoman:~$ systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
Failed to issue method call: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/postgresql_4010_2dmain_2eservice
```

Comment: Have you tried running `apt -y update && apt -y upgrade` before running the installation? I was able to successfully installed on Ubuntu 14.04 after an update and upgrade.

Comment: No, Is there is any other way since upgrade will take atleast of 1GB update

Comment: Not that I know for 14.04, there's a way for 17.04. Might work for 14.04 as well. https://dev.to/pauloxnet/upgrading-postgresql-from-95-to-96-on-ubuntu-1704

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The accepted answer in [postgresql-fails-to-reinstall-after-upgrading-ubuntu-12-04-to-14-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873091/postgresql-fails-to-reinstall-after-upgrading-ubuntu-12-04-to-14-04) worked for me.

For easy reference I paste the instructions from that link below:

> Checking `/etc/init.d/postgresql` file it uses `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions`.
>   This file executes `/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster` to start and stop postgresql server.

```
if [ "$1" = "stop" ] || [ "$1" = "restart" ]; then
    ERRMSG=$(pg_ctlcluster --force "$2" "$name" $1 2>&1)
else
    ERRMSG=$(pg_ctlcluster "$2" "$name" $1 2>&1)
fi
```

> `/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster` file accepts `--skip-systemctl-redirect` option to start or stop postgresql without systemctl. 
>   So you need to add `--skip-systemctl-redirect` in `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions` in `do_ctl_all()` function. So it will look like this.

```
if [ "$1" = "stop" ] || [ "$1" = "restart" ]; then
    ERRMSG=$(pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect --force "$2" "$name" $1 2>&1)
else
    ERRMSG=$(pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect "$2" "$name" $1 2>&1)
fi
```

> Or you can add `$skip_systemctl_redirect = 1;` before `$skip_systemctl_redirect` is checked in `/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster`.

Screenshot of original answer:
[image: screenshot of original answer]